# Add bearer token to ajax POST request in ASP.Net Core

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core

I have a POST method `/Home/PostRequest` decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute in ASP.Net Core.  Client-side I have an authenticated user.  I want to construct an ajax POST request to call the method, but I'm unsure what to put into the Authorization header. Where are the auth credentials cached, and in what form?

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/PostRequest",
            data: JSON.stringify(request),
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "** what to put here? **"
            }
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: false,
            success: function (response) {
                successCallback(response);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                console.log("Failed");
            },
            error: function (xhr, response, thrownError) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        });
```

Comment: what kind of authorization did you add with your `AddAuthentication()` function?

Comment: We have .AddMicrosoftAccount() and .AddAmazon(). In practice we would like to add other OAuth providers.  I'm hoping I don't also have to configure a JWT provider. :-)

Comment: I'll add that I can push info via the active Razor view but I'd prefer a static client-side javascript solution.

Comment: Those authentication providers should be setting an auth cookie so there's no need to add an Authorization header.

Comment: Functions like `AddMicrosoftAccount` will help you set up the connection to the respective accounts, you will still need to set up an authorization scheme such as cookies and set it as default. If you have done this, you don't have to pass any headers from js as the cookies would take care of it

Comment: can you post the authentication part of your start up class for clarity? You can hide out the sensitive information alone

Comment: Thanks all, per @Brad 's response, everything Just Works via the auth cookie.